# 4-Sequences {0...9}

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My questions are given the set {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},

1) How many 4-sequences are there?

(would this be $10*10 * 10 * 10 = 10,000)? $ since the max possible numbers given to each 4 slots is 10.

2) How many 4 sequences does not begin with 9?

(this would be $9 * 9 * 9 * 9 = 6,561$ since it would be 1 less digit?)

3) How many 4 sequence begin and end with 9?

4) How many 4 sequence do not begin and end with 9?

5) How many 4 sequence do not begin OR end with 0?

Comment: Hint:  for $2$ it's only the first digit that is restricted.

Comment: For number 2 you answer all of the 4 sequences that have no 9s anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all of them multiply the choices of each slot.  The only issue is to identify which options are available for each slot.

1) all for sequences.

Ergo 10 choices each slot.  Answer: $10*10*10*10 = 10,000$.

2) sequences not beginning with 9.

Ergo 9 choices for first slot and 10 for all others.  Answer: $1*10*10*10 = 1,000$

3) sequences beginning and ending with 0.

Ergo 1 choice for the first and last slot and 10 for all others.  Answer: $1*10*10*1 = 100$.

4) do not begin and end with 9.

Oh.  THis is a little different.  But this is #1) all sequences minus #3) *do* begin and end with 9.  Answer: 10,000 - 100 = 9,900$.

Another way:

do not begin and end with 9 means.  Does not begin with 9. plus those that begin with nine but do not end with 9.

Those with 9 choices for the first.  Plus those with 1 choice for the first and 9 for the last.

Answer: $9*10*10*10 + 1*10*10*9 = 9,000 + 900 = 9,900$.

5) (Actually easier than 4).  Do not begin or end with 0.

Ergo 9 choices for first and last and 10 for the others.  Answer: $9*10*10*9 = 8,100$.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming repetition is allowed.) For the first one, you are correct, there are ten choices for each slot, so $10^4$ total possibilities.

For the second, note that the first digit has $9$ possibilities now. The rest still have $10$.

To get you started on three, note that there is only $1$ choice for the first slot, $10$ for the middle slots, and $1$ for the last slot.

For $4$ and $5$, you may want to consider starting with all possible $4$-sequences, and then subtracting the "illegal" ones.

Comment: So i got: 1) = 10,000....2) = 9,000 . . . 3) = 100 . . . 4) = 8,000 . . . 5) = 8,000 ?

Comment: We know that $100$ sequences begin AND end with a $9$. For five, see the other answer.